# Twitter bootstrap-collapse: highlighting selected collapse item

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors, accordion

I want to highlight the selected collapse item. To achieve this, I added new classes (accordion-heading-highlighted and accordion-group-highlighted) with addClass() method for the accordion-heading and accordion-group but there is a problem.

If I clicked on a collapsible item while it is closed, it works fine. However, if I clicked on a collapsible item which is opened, it's accordion-heading background color couldn't change to the original one.

You can test it on here: http://jsfiddle.net/uuZAK/

How can I fix this?

The HTML is:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        s1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        s2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
        Collapsible Group Item #3
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body in collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        s3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.accordion-heading {
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion-heading a {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-heading-active {
  background: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion-heading-active a {
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion-heading-active a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion-group-active {
  border: 2px #444 solid;
}
```

The JavaScript + jQuery (1.7.2) is:

```
$(function(){
    $('.accordion').collapse();
    // highlight default collapse item
    var $init;
    $init = $(".accordion-body.in");
    $init.parent().addClass("accordion-group-active");
    $init.prev().addClass("accordion-heading-active");
});

$(".accordion-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".accordion-heading").removeClass("accordion-heading-active");
    $(".accordion-heading").parents(".accordion-group").removeClass("accordion-group-active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("accordion-heading-active");
    $(this).parents(".accordion-group").addClass("accordion-group-active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios here that you have to account for:

1. If the user clicks the active item, deactivate it
2. If the user clicks an inactive item, deactivate all items, then activate this one.

Your current solution has no way of detecting which item is already active. You can use the `$.hasClass` function to check if the item you've clicked is already active.

Here's a forked jsFiddle with the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Willyham/6v7Rn/

Comment: there is a bug in this type of implementation. Double clicking any header during transition accidently removes the class back to onrmal even if the collapse is open.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind on `hide` and `show` event of `accordion-body` to set status for the collapse item. No issue with double-click.

I reuse the code of Will Demaine. Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kXTc6/1/